# Android: Pausing and restart audio on new Activity, but pause and resume on screen rotate

Tags: android, audio, rotation, restart

I have an android app where in my Main activity I can play music onCreate(), pause music onPause() and restart music onResume(). I am using MediaPlayer. The problem is that I don't want the music to restart onResume() when I'm rotating the screen on my Main activity. I only want the music to restart when I'm coming back to my Main activity from another activity. Any suggestions?

> private MediaPlayer mp;
>
> mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.always_sunny);
> mp.setLooping(true);
> mp.start();
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onPause() {
>   super.onPause();
>   mp.getCurrentPosition();
>   mp.pause();
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onResume() {
>   super.onResume();
>   mp.seekTo(0);
>   mp.start();
> }
> ```

Comment: The issue with the music is resolved, but now there is a new issue. I am using both portrait and landscape layout for my Main activity. I have it set up so that my portrait and landscape layout uses two different images for one of the ImageView in my layouts. Unfortunately for me, android:configChanges="orientation" also prevents the image from changing when the screen rotates to and from portrait to landscape. So how will I be able to change my ImageView image source on screen rotate, but also prevent the audio playing in my Main activity from restarting on screen rotate?

Comment: Can I keep android:configChanges="orientation" in the AndroidManifest.xml and maybe programmatically check if the device is in portrait/landscape mode and set the image source that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following attribute to the activity in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

This would avoid that the activity restarts on orientation changes or when the keyboard appears.

If you need to do something when the rotation changes (for example, change an image in your case), add the following method to your activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig) {
  // Change here your image
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the music does not restart on orientation changes. I would vote up but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Good to know that it solved your problem! I think you can still accept the answer with the green check symbol if it was useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a portrait and landscape image that changes on screen rotate. setting android:configChanges prevents the music from stopping on screen rotate, but I wanted the image to change on rotate. It seems I need another solution besides setting android:configChanges as I tried to keep that setting and change the imageview image source in my Main activity java file and it didn't work with the setting enabled.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the method that is fired on orientation changes. There you can modify the imageview.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm now able to prevent music from restarting but allow the image to change on screen rotation.